# Child categories not appearing in wordpress admin menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a plugin and adding some categories

some categories are child categories for instance:

- Clothes

  - Hats
  - Shirts

I add my category like this:

```
function addCategory($name, $description, $slug){
  $term = wp_insert_term( $name, 'product_cat', [
  'description'=> $description,
  'slug' => $slug ]
  );
  if ( is_wp_error( $term ) ) {
     $term_id = $term->error_data['term_exists'] || null;
     return false;
  } else {
     $term_id = $term['term_id'];
     add_term_meta ($term_id, "display_style", "products", true);
     return $term_id;
  }
}
```

if in my category object the `parent_id` is different from `0` then I call this function:

```
function updateParentID($localID, $parentLocalID){
  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'term_taxonomy';
  $sql ="UPDATE $table_name SET parent = $parentLocalID WHERE  term_id = $localID";
  $rez = $wpdb->query($sql);
  return $rez;
}
```

If I check my `term_taxonomy` table I do have the right ID for the `parent` field.

However if on the admin panel I check the categories I can't see the categories but the item count is at 4:

[image: missing categories]

If I click the Name column to filter by alphabetical order then they appear:

[image: appeared]

From what I can see they are correctly linked in the database:

[image: database linked]

I noticed in the admin panel if I edit a child category and just save without changing any details then they will appear correctly:

[image: good rendering]

How could get them to show all the time. Am I missing something when adding the parent.

**Note:**

I noticed in the docs there's a `wp_update_term` but I couldn't find any `wp_update_term_taxonomy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to make the update work but have to use `wp_update_term`

In the end I get this code:

```
function updateParentID($localID, $parentLocalID){
  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'term_taxonomy';
  $value = wp_update_term( $localID, 'product_cat', array( 'parent' => $parentLocalID ) );
  if ( is_wp_error( $value ) ) {
    return $value->get_error_message();;
  }else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set parent/child of the term, why you are using separate custom query($wpdb->query())? Well, but i think you can use the parent parameter which is in wp_insert_term parameter it self.

Example,

```
wp_insert_term(
'Banana', // the term 
'product_cat', // the taxonomy
array(
  'description'=> 'Sweet banana',
  'slug' => 'banana',
  'parent'=> $parent_term_id  
 )
);
```

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't add it at that moment. My data comes from an API and thus I will only have the parent ID of the remote database I need add all categories and then for all child categories get the local id then add it to the parent field.